# Check C++ enum without initializer for multiple values

Tags: c++

I've a C++ enum without initializers that I can't change.

```
enum Foo {A,B,C};
```

Because it's not initialized with power of 2 values I can't easily use bit operators to build masks, etc. to check against (Foo::A | Foo::B). Is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes there's a way around it, if you remember that enumerations always start at `0` and are then sequentially numbered. Instead of using it as a bit-mask, use it as a bit-number from which you can construct a mask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see a way other than wrapping your `Foo::X`-values by a function or a macro that transforms the bit-number into a mask or defining analogously named constants to be used.

The definition of the function / macro is rather easy, since you can use the `Foo::X`-values directly as bit numbers (and therefore as input to bit shift operator `<<`).

These approaches could look as follows:

```
enum Foo {A,B,C};

constexpr unsigned int Foo_A = 1 << Foo::A;
constexpr unsigned int Foo_B = 1 << Foo::B;
constexpr unsigned int Foo_C = 1 << Foo::C;

constexpr unsigned int AsBit(enum Foo f) { return 1 << f; }

#define ASBIT(f) (1 << f)

int main() {

    unsigned int val = Foo_A | Foo_C;
    cout << val << endl;  // Output: 5

    val = AsBit(Foo::A) | AsBit(Foo::B);
    cout << val << endl;  // Output: 3

    val = ASBIT(Foo::B) | ASBIT(Foo::C);
    cout << val << endl;  // Output: 6

}
```

Another way could be to overload operator `|`, but I'd not encourage it. It would let a program behave differently than one expects:

```
enum Foo {A,B,C};

unsigned int operator | (enum Foo f1, enum Foo f2) {
    return (1<<f1) | (1<<f2);
}

int main() {

    unsigned int val = Foo::A | Foo::C;
    cout << val << endl;  // Output: 5
}
```